# How To Add image in the letter head of the Email by smtp mail message object in c #.net?

Tags: c#

I have a requirement to display image in the letter of the SMTP Mail in C#.net ? How To Add image in the letter head of the Email by smtp mail message object in c #.net through programatically ?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212838/c-sharp-sending-mails-with-images-inline-using-smtpclient

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ContentID of the IMAGE tag to reference an image in the HTML body of your email like this:

```
    <IMG SRC="cid:content-id" />
```

Then you add the image as a linked resource to the alternateviews part of the mailmessage:

```
    AlternateView body = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(m_msg.Body,null,"text/html");
    //create the LinkedResource (embedded image)
    LinkedResource embimg= new LinkedResource(filename,System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
    logo.ContentId = cid; // content-id used in image tag
    body.LinkedResources.Add(embimg);

    m_msg.AlternateViews.Add(body);
```