# How do you set ContentDisposition in a LinkedResource?

Tags: .net, vb.net, system.net.mail, system.net

Is there a way to set the `ContentDisposition` of a `LinkedResource` to be `inline`, ie in the case of an image?

Here's how I am building my `LinkedResource` right now:

```
            Dim img As LinkedResource = New LinkedResource(filePath)

            Dim fileType As String = ""
            Dim attName As String = "image" + fileName + "." + fileExt

            If (fileExt = "jpg" Or fileExt = "jpeg") Then
                img.ContentType.MediaType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg
            ElseIf (fileExt = "gif") Then
                img.ContentType.MediaType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Gif
            ElseIf (fileExt = "png") Then
                img.ContentType.MediaType = "image/png"
            End If

            img.ContentId = attName
            img.ContentType.Name = attName
            linkedResources.Add(img)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapt the code succinctly described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11000938

This appears to be the right approach. Articles describing this in more detail include these:

- http://asknoor.wordpress.com/2013/02/21/sending-emails-with-embedded-images-in-html-view-using-linked-resources-class/
- http://www.razafayyaz.com/2012/12/sending-html-emails-with-embedded.html

Answer (score 0):

`LinkedResources` already sets the `ContentDisposition` to `inline`.

In fact, `LinkedResources` appears to exist only for the purpose of adding hidden embedded images and other `inline` content to your `AlternateView`.  There is no option to set a filename, since users will never see it.

Use `Attachments` when you want visible, user-accessible files attached to your email, with filenames.

Use `LinkedResources` when you want hidden resources such as embedded images in your email, which you then reference in HTML with cid:.

Comment: I'm not seeing the ContentDisposition being set when I use LinkedResources.

Comment: Exactly as @SimonParker stated.

Comment: Unfortunately it's been some years and several .NET versions since I've worked with System.Mail- it's possible they've changed something here- but it seems unlikely. LinkedResources and Attachments are still separate mechanisms. I'd recommend digging into the docs and experimenting with different calls.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.linkedresource?view=net-6.0

Comment: Also check the actual email content you're generating- mail readers vary widely in how they render embedded content, and some will show them as attachments.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a "ContentType.Name" value will make it an attachment.