# Embedding Image with SMTP email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

I am using HTML template for sending mail through SMTP by using **MailDefinition**.
But when I send a mail texts are sending properly. But Images are not getting displayed in received mail. I read somewhere that I should use **Linked Resource**  for embedding logo in templated mail. But I am not able to do it. Is there any other suggestion to embed image using **MailDefinition** ? Thank you.

Comment: Covered in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212838/c-sharp-sending-mails-with-images-inline-using-smtpclient

Comment: See this MSDN documentation on the EmbeddedMailObject class, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.EmbeddedMailObject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.